Receiving 18 bytes of USB device descriptor if bMaxPacketSize is 8 bytes with MAX3421E
I am trying to use the MAX3421E as host to read a FTDI peripheral. I can set the USB address successfully, however, I can only read the first 8 bytes of the device descriptor.
I am sending this as a setup transfer type to the address asigned to the peripheral:
  uint8_t req_type  = 0x80; // device to host, standard, device recipient
  uint8_t req       = 6;    // GET_DESCRIPTOR
  uint8_t wvalue_l  = 0x00; // descriptor_index: 
  uint8_t wvalue_h  = 0x01; // descriptor_type: DEVICE
  uint8_t windex_l  = 0x00;
  uint8_t windex_h  = 0x00;
  uint8_t wlength_l = 18;
  uint8_t wlength_h = 0x00; // 18 bytes to transfer in data stage

After sending GET_DESCRIPTOR I request a BULK-IN, I receive only 8 bytes:
0x12 0x01 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x08

The device is answering with 0x12 bLength (18 bytes) which is correct, but the MAX3421E is only receiving 8 bytes. I suspect this is because bMaxPacketSize=0x08. How can I receive all 18 bytes of the device descriptor?. I have tried the following:
SETUP GET_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR (ACK)
BULK_IN REQUEST (received only 8 bytes)
BULK_IN REQUEST (Peripheral returned NAK)
HANDSHAKE-OUT (ACK)


For some reason, the second bulk-in request after a succesfull bulk-in always returns NAK. The exchange looks like this:
SETUP GET_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR (ACK)
BULK_IN REQUEST (received only 8 bytes)
BULK_IN REQUEST (Peripheral returned NAK)
BULK_IN REQUEST (received 8 bytes more)
BULK_IN REQUEST (Peripheral returned NAK)
BULK_IN REQUEST (received remaining 2 bytes)
HANDSHAKE-OUT (ACK)

